# Access jhipster Oauth2 authenticated REST API in ionic app

Tags: angularjs, oauth, ionic-framework, jhipster

While accessing **jhipster** **Oauth2** API in my **ionic app** but I am getting                        no response. This is the **$http** request I am sending from my ionic app

```
$http({
    method: "post", 
    url: "http://192.168.0.5:8080/auth-2-sconnect/oauth/token",
    data:  "username=admin&password=admin&grant_type=password&scope=read write&client_secret=my-secret-token-to-change-in-production&client_id=auth2Sconnectapp",
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: {
      'Accept':'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      }
  })                
  .success(function(data) {
      alert("success: " + data);
  })
  .error(function(data, status) {
      alert("ERROR: " + data);
  });
```

it also gives **`Status Code:403 Forbidden**` error if I insert

```
'Authorization': 'Basic ' + 'YXV0aDJTY29ubmVjdGFwcDpteS1zZWNyZXQtdG9rZW4tdG8tY2hhbmdlLWluLXByb2R1Y3Rpb24='
```

inside **headers**

Comment: did you check for proxies?

Comment: both jhipster application and ionic app are running on my local machine

Comment: did u try using this url?  `url: "http://localhost:8080/auth-2-sconnect/oauth/token",`

Comment: my jhipster app is running on localhost which is 192.168.0.5 with tomcat port 8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I un-commented CORS in application.yml of jhipster application, that seems to do the trick.

My ionic application is working fine now.